# Getting PFObject from Selected Row and Saving to Another Parse Class

Tags: uitableview, swift, parse-platform, uibutton, pfobject

I am still new to programming and I am trying to create a button that will save the `currentUser` and the `EventID` of a `PFObject`. I have a class in Parse called Users Attendance that relates the User with the `EventID` to keep track of all the events a user says they will attend. I am having trouble setting up the UIButton to save the EventID from the PFObject that is on the row selected it from the `TableView`. Could someone please help?

Here is the TableView setup:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! EventsTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = EventsTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    cell.attend.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.attend.addTarget(self, action: "attendingEvent:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell

    if let eventTime = object?["EventTime"] as? String {
    cell.EventTime.text = eventTime
    }

    if let eventName = object?["EventName"] as? String {
        cell.EventName.text = eventName
    }

    var initialImage = UIImage(named: "DidNotLoad")
    cell.EventImage.image = initialImage
    if let parseEventPhoto = object?["EventImage"] as? PFFile{
        cell.EventImage.file = parseEventPhoto
        cell.EventImage.loadInBackground()
    }
    return cell
}
```

Here is the `UIButton` I attempted to create:

```
func attendingEvent(sender: UIButton) {

    println("You tapped the button!")

    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    var getSenderInfo = sender.tag
    var selectedRowInfo = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var objectFromRow = objectAtIndexPath(selectedRowInfo)

    let eventID: PFObject = objectFromRow?["EventID"] as! PFObject

    println(eventID)

    var attendance = PFObject(className: "UsersAttendance")
    attendance.setObject(currentUser!, forKey: "AttendingUser")
    attendance.setObject(eventID, forKey: "EventID")

    attendance.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {


    } else {

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you checked what `selectedRowInfo` is - it might not be what you expect... You also don't actually describe exactly what's wrong, this could be the problem but it's hard to be sure...

Comment: When I tap the button to save the EventID it does not save it back to Parse. Instead I get this error "invalid type for key EventID, expected *Events, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.7.1)"

Comment: Then the problem is that the code doesn't match the expectation based on the model you have created in the Parse web interface...

Comment: I created the EventID in the Parse Class as a pointer to another class? Would that cause the issue? It didn't throw an error when I save the currentUser...

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably take a different approach and add a relationship from the Event class to the User class and populate that with attendees.

That said, your problem is due to a mismatch between the `EventID` on the source and destination objects. In one case it's a string and in the other it's a pointer so you can't use them interchangeably.

You have other issues with this approach, though you may be protecting against them, like always creating new `UsersAttendance` instances which you need some other way to check if there is already an item for this user and event and some other way to remove old ones.